# Nodejs server doesn't send response after some time

Tags: node.js, restify

Can you help me? 
I tried jmeter testing with nodejs server but after some 5000 requests node server doesn't respond, So I have to restart the server to make it work again. is there any way to make it work again without restarting the server?

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is a way to treat the symptoms without treating the cause.  I know of no way to "make it work again" but if we can find the cause of your problem we can fix it and remove the symptoms.  It is difficult to comment on what exactly is happening without more information/code, but two things come to mind.

1. You may be performing some very heavy computations and accidentally blocking your event loop.  [This](http://zef.me/blog/4561/node-js-and-the-case-of-the-blocked-event-loop) article discusses it in more detail.
2. You may have a memory leak which is crashing node.  This is easy to check by watching the memory usage of node on windows task manager or a mac/linux equivalent.  If the memory keeps increasing and never falls, Node may reach its max memory limit and crash.  The only way I know of to fix this is to run the node garbage collector manually.  [This](https://simonmcmanus.wordpress.com/2013/01/03/forcing-garbage-collection-with-node-js-and-v8/) article talks about it.  This is of course a temporary solution, you should fix the memory leak if you find one.

Those are the only two I can think of.  If you want more help, I'll need to see your code.

Answer (score -2):

you can use 'forever': https://github.com/foreverjs/forever

but I think you know why the script fails.

Good luck

Comment: forever is only for running in background. not for assuring to work under pressure.

Comment: why did you flagged my comment.  let me know if I am wrong. I am ready to delete the comment. If you can give satisfactory answer.

Comment: are you talking to me? I don't flag anything